# Handling moment objects out of scope

Tags: javascript, prototype, electron, momentjs

I pass an array of moment objects in electron using ipc from main to the renderer, both include moment library, but when I try to call moment's functions on those objects in the renderer, it's like they're not moment objects anymore.

That's the object:

[image]

If I try to call `format` or other moment methods I get an error.

I'd rather not use the private fields in that object, so how can I make those objects be moment's objects again?

Edit:

This is how I pass the objects:

main.js: `mainWindow.webContents.send('error-lines', errorLines);`

Printing errorLines (part of it):

```
[ { id: '6',
    date: moment("2017-11-01T07:25:36.000"),
    start: false },
  { id: '5',
    date: moment("2017-11-01T08:01:40.000"),
    start: false },
  { id: '5', date: moment("2017-11-01T16:46:32.000"), start: true },
  { id: '6', date: moment("2017-11-01T17:11:11.000"), start: true },
```

renderer:

```
ipc.on('error-lines', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Can you supply the code your using to pass the object around?

Comment: `temp1` in your screenshot **is** a moment object (see `_isAMomentObject: true` property). Can you share the code that generate your issue?

Comment: See the screenshot now, the prototype is empty of moment's methods. @VincenzoC

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3923), I don't know enough about electron ipc, but it seems that you can't pass _complex_ objects (like moment objects) using `webContents.send`.

Comment: @VincenzoC so I have no choice but to use the private fields?

Comment: I think you can remove moment from your `errorLines` (or use something like `format()` or `toISOString()` and create moment objects in your renderer part. Unfortunately I don't know enough about electron ipc, so I don't know what is the best thing to do in this case.

Comment: [moment.js docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) says it works in the browser. Have you installed it, or have a <script> CDN reference in your html?

Comment: It's included and this app should work offline so no cdns. @radarbob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

electron's ipc between process does not allow non-serializable objects and only sends plain object over, so this is expected. You may send only plain object and reconstruct object on receiver process side to have full object you want.

Comment: IMHO the best way to do this for moment objects is not to pass the serialized object but to pass the date as ISO date format using moment's `.toISOString()` method.